# How to retrieve the filter options in Magento 2 REST API in category list?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How can we retrieve the filter options in a category with REST API?

In the product category page, I have the filters as below and it depends on each category.

- Product Category Filter
- Filter by stock
- Filter by on stock
- Filter by price
- Filter by Manufacturer

etc......

So I just want to retrieve this values in REST API. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried search criteria ?

Comment: @AdityaShah Actually, I just want to list all the available filters for the particular category. I'm not aware of the search criteria. If you can point out that would be better. Thanks

Comment: I added an answer

Comment: @AdityaShah updated the Qn.

Comment: Well,I have provided a link.

Comment: did  you find anything? @ShafeequeS

Answer (score -1):

> How can we retrieve the filter options in a category with REST API?

```
GET    /V1/categories/:categoryId/products
```

**Now, apply `searchCriteria`**

The **[searchCriteria query parameter](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/performing-searches.html)** allows you to search across multiple objects in a collection. You can use the fields query parameter in conjunction with searchCriteria to limit the output. The question mark (?) that precedes fields in all the other examples in this document is replaced with an ampersand (&).

The following query returns only the `sku` and name parameters for product items whose `category_gear` attribute includes the value **86**.

```
GET http://<host>/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_gear&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=86&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=finset&fields=items[sku,name]
```

**example**

```
GET http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=WSH%2529%25&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=sku&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=WP%2529%25&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=like&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=price&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=40&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=from&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][field]=price&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][value]=49.99&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][2][filters][0][condition_type]=to
```

Comment: I think the question is to get the available filters for a particular category.

Comment: Yes @Mohitchauhan We can achieve this by above :) for particular category you need to pass specific ID in here -> /V1/categories/:categoryId

Comment: Question is for available layer navigation filter by current category/current id Not  search by category